# Errors do not appear in HTML editor

Tags: html

In the Developer Console I have 3 validation errors:

1 Custom JavaScript is not allowed.
2 The attribute 'href' in tag 'link rel=stylesheet for fonts' is set to the invalid value
3 Custom JavaScript is not allowed.

They all lead me to this line:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://gc.kis.v2.scr.kaspersky-labs.com/FD126C42-EBFA-4E12-B309-BB3FDD723AC1/main.js?attr=7PvfiK9pscH_YbT4h4nStCdYNjBw0nMNsfADSIuT0zx_tZQSNlZEYY9srv3HGM3P8N3pj2oX3lW3Q440_CzRnQ" charset="UTF-8"></script><link rel="stylesheet" crossorigin="anonymous" href="http://gc.kis.v2.scr.kaspersky-labs.com/E3E8934C-235A-4B0E-825A-35A08381A191/abn/main.css?attr=aHR0cDovLzEyNy4wLjAuMTo1NTAwL2luZGV4Lmh0bWw"/><style amp-custom>
```

But in the HTML editor (Visual studio) that line never appears, how do I eliminate those errors?
I appreciate your help

Comment: Hi Fer, Please attach your code to the question so that we can review and reproduce the error and provide you with better help.

Comment: HTML editors and browsers have their own separate implementations of HTML parsers - they don't agree on many things, this is one of those things.

Answer (score 1):

This line added to the browser because of Kaspersky Security Cloud. Visit other websites and look if the `<script>` tag added to them as well.

The solution is deactivating the Kaspersky product.